# Android - Manipulating the touchscreen input location

Tags: android, drivers, touchscreen

I'm with not much experience in Android development.
I'm considering a big project and before getting deeply into it, I want to check whether my requirements are even possible:

My goal is to manipulate the system by changing the coordinates of a user's touch on the touchscreen. For example: If a user is touching the screen on point (X,Y), I want **any opened application** to act like the user touched (X+5,Y-3).

I have thought on a few levels that this may be possible to be defined in:
Touch-screen's driver level, OS level, application level (i.e. background application).
A big advantage will be to built it in a way that will allow as much compatibility as possible.

What is the best/right way to do it?

I'm not looking for a full solution, only a hint regarding the best direction to start digging...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I'm with not much experience in Android development.` and then `I'm considering a big project` and bit later `My goal is to manipulate the system`...

Comment: Like @MarcinOrlowski has suggested. Get some experience and start off in a much smaller scope before biting off much more than you can chew. You may even stumble across the answer while you learn more about android dev.

Comment: Well, since this is a really big project with a lot of eapects and different possible solutions - some of them are not android based, I wanted to find out first if the android option is even relevant and how complicated it will be. A lot of time and effort will be put on this, so yes, I don't have much knowledge in this point but I want to know if the effort should be put in this direction.
Please consider your answers again and remember that this place's goal is to help each other. Thanks.